# Display user data from api based on search value using angular primeng

Tags: javascript, angular, angular7, primeng

I am working on Angular 7 application using angular primeng and new to Angular. This is the scenario.

a) Fetched user data from external api but i need to display user based on the input search. I tried to read the following documentation "Multiple" select https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/autocomplete but not able to display value based on the search.

b) I have added Add button on the right side of search section. Upon clicking the add button, user should be displayed below it.

Please see the code snippet.
home.component.html

```
<div class="ui-g">
      <div class="ui-g-9">
        <p-autoComplete [(ngModel)]="patients" [suggestions]="filteredUsersMultiple" (completeMethod)="filterCountryMultiple($event)"
          [minLength]="1" placeholder="Users" field="name" [multiple]="true">
        </p-autoComplete>
        <ul>
            <li *ngFor="let c of patients">{{c}}</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="ui-g-3">
        <button pButton type="button" label="Add" class="ui-button-secondary"></button>
      </div>    
    </div>
```

country.service.ts

```
export class CountryService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getUsers() {
    return this.http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users');
  }
}
```

home.component.ts

```
filterCountryMultiple(event) {
    this.userService.getUsers().subscribe(
      (val: any[]) => {
        this.filteredUsersMultiple = val.map(user => user.username);
        console.log(this.filteredUsersMultiple);
      }
    )
  }
```

It would be really helpful if somebody could help me to find on how to display user data based on searching and display it when clicking Add button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the doc https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/autocomplete use completeMethod to query for the results. The event contains the query text. Then create a search function and compare both query and the filteredUsersMultiple.

```
filterCountryMultiple(event) {
    let query = event.query; 
    this.userService.getUsers().subscribe(
      (val: any[]) => {
        this.filteredUsersMultiple = val.map(user => user.username);
        this.checkUsers = this.mySearch(query, this.filteredUsersMultiple);
      });
  }

  mySearch(query, filteredUsersMultiple: any[]):any[] {
    let filtered : any[] = [];
    for(let i = 0; i < filteredUsersMultiple.length; i++) {
      let data = filteredUsersMultiple[i];
      if(data.toLowerCase().indexOf(query.toLowerCase()) == 0) {
          filtered.push(data);
      }
  }
```